# Is Ragtags a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen the word ragtag in various places. Just want to be sure about Ragtags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Probably not. If you are using "ragtag" as an adjective, definitely not because English adjectives do not have number (single/plural). If you are using "ragtag" as a noun (which is debatably nonstandard), then "ragtags" would be acceptable.

Comment: Yep, "ragtag" is normally an adjective, meaning "untidy" or "ragged".  It may occasionally be "nounified" to refer to an unkempt person, in which case the plural "ragtags" would be appropriate to refer to a group of unkempt folks.